# How to install gauge as package on Ubuntu 18 with apt?

Tags: ubuntu, gauge

This is my system:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

I use the following instructions: https://docs.gauge.org/getting_started/installing-gauge.html?os=linux&language=java&ide=vscode#step-1-installing-gauge-on-linux

but the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gauge
```

leads to

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Err:2 https://dl.bintray.com/gauge/gauge-deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                     
  403  Forbidden
```

Is there now Gauge package for my Ubuntu version?

The NPM variant of the installation described under the same URL leads to

```
 sudo npm install -g @getgauge/cli
/usr/local/bin/gauge -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli/bin/gauge

> @getgauge/cli@1.1.8 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli
> node ./src/index.js

Fetching download url for Gauge version 1.1.8
Downloading https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/releases/download/v1.1.8/gauge-1.1.8-linux.x86_64.zip to ./bin
TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function
    at ClientRequest.once (events.js:340:11)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:164:10)
    at Object.request (http.js:38:10)
    at Object.request (https.js:239:15)
    at Object.get (https.js:243:21)
    at downloadFollowingRedirect (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli/src/index.js:13:11)
    at Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli/src/index.js:30:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at downloadAndExtract (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli/src/index.js:28:12)
    at install.getVersion.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@getgauge/cli/src/index.js:38:18)
    at <anonymous>
```

and gauge exists in /usr/local/bin/gauge afterwards. Why does the normal variant with a package not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened an issue on their Github and it seems this deb repository is dropped. There you can check the new procedure to install that on Ubuntu:

https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/1990